# Laptop screen brightness irritates me at night

Tags: light, laptop

When I am using my laptop at night, the laptop light irritates me, despite the fact that my laptop brightness is normal. Please tell me how to overcome this problem.

Comment: What operating system (and what laptop model) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've set the brightness to lowest and the screen is still too bright for you, there are many dimmer programs you can download for free. (PangoBright, for example, allows you to dim the screen up to 20% and also change the hue. If 20% is still too bright, you can use it together with another dimmer.) Do some searching on screen dimmers and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10 Settings, for controlling the brightness of your device. Go to "Settings" and then select "System". Now under "Display", you will find a "Change Brightness" slider at the top. Move that slider to adjust the brightness of your device.

If your device comes with sensors capable of light intensity detection, then you might also see "Change brightness automatically when lighting changes" checkbox below the slider. Enable this Adaptive Brightness feature if you want the brightness to be automatically adjusted.

Another simple solution may to get a tinted sheet of Plexiglas or something to put in front of the screen to make it dimmer.

See also: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/how-to-decrease-laptop-led-backlight-screen-to-its-minimum.433375/

Answer (score 4):

There is an application called F.lux, which reduces blue light and irritation to eyes during the evening.  It is available on most platforms, including phones and tablets.

EDIT:  This program can be set up to individual preferences.  For instance, you can change the warmth of the light depending on your own preferences.  As well, it has the ability to change states depending on your timezone's sunrise/sunset times, how quickly the changes occur, and even the ability to expand the range to warmer colors than is typically available directly from a base install [although this requires a restart of your system].  All in all, I find this has more features and customizations than other offerings, be they OS or other software.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you already reduced the brightness of the screen as much as possible as well as chose a pleasant dark desktop theme. Your remaining options are:

1. **Turn the ambient light on** in the room (will make your pupils contracting and therefore will make your eyes less sensitive to the laptop light).
2. Put some grey filter in front of your screen. Experiment with grey plastic foil.
3. Put some grey filter in front of your eyes. Use some kind of very light sun glasses.